# Is root module and root component have separate injector?

Tags: angular

**"Root injector"** is related to *ngModule* or its a part of *bootstrapped component*? in documentation its said that when we create component parallel injector tree gets created. But when we talk about "root injector", so that injector is part of ngModule(AppModule) or root component, or both have separate injectors?